# Get center of Shape intersection (2D)

Tags: java, 2d, intersection, shapes

I'm using the Slick java game lib and I've used the Slick implementation of [Shape](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Shape.html) as a hit-box for collision and that's working fine. I use `shape1.intersects(shape2)` for checking if two shapes overlap. Now what I want to do is get the center point of the intersecting shape to use as a place to generate particles showing the collision between the 2 objects.

I can't find any explanations of algorithms that calculate shape intersections, maybe because I don't know if it has a specific name or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, there seem to be two methods -- `union` and `subtract` -- using which you can get the intersection as follows:

```
A ∩ B  =  A ∪ B - (A - B) - (B - A)
```

The only problem is that those methods seem to return an array of shapes instead of a single shape, whatever that means.

Of course, doing this in real-time could be quite costly, so you could alternatively approximate the collision point to be in between the centres of the bounding box/circle of the two shapes.

Comment: If I make a line between the 2 centers and apply the above intersection using the bounding radius then that should be close enough to not matter - Thanks